# Retrieving Blob URL from MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am currently facing an issue with my coding process.
I have stored a blob data type image onto my MySQL database table and I want to retrieve only the URL of that specific blob image using PHP storing that onto a global variable which later will be used as a `body background='echo $blob Url'`.

I have tried multiple scenarios but none seem to be working and the body background will be a custom background that will be set by the user upload rather than the default background located on the CSS.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

```
$image= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'"id="avatar">';
```

If I use the code above, I successfully display the image onto the PHP page, but what I want is to retrieve the image URL which appear as shown below on view image on new tab

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHB.....
```

I want to store that URL for that particular image and store it onto a variable.

Comment: We would understand your question better if you showed us the code you have tried and sample blob data from DB.

Comment: @Dharman i have edited the question and have added code sample and about the trial code, i unfortunately dont have it because it was giving me error.

Comment: This does not look like a [BLOB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) at all. I think you mean a base64 encoded image string?

Comment: @MarkusZeller I think OP meant it is saved as blob in MySQL

Comment: He said BLOB URL, not BLOB field. That's a big difference.

Comment: It looks like there is a missing space before id attribute.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what you mean. Even with the code example I am clueless what you are asking. What URL? What variable? Store it where? Blob or base64?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Spaces are optional in HTML

Comment: @MarkusZeller Sorry about that, Dharman is right, what i meant was that the image is saved as blob in MySQL

Comment: @Dharman I want to retrieve the image from the mysql database which is in blob datatype, save the image url inside a variable to that i can echo it as a normal image link taken from the internet.

Comment: Does `base64_encode($row['image'])` really produce forward slashes?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you SELECT it from the database?

Comment: @Dharman "select backgroundPic from user where Username = '$username'"; That is the select statement.

Comment: @MarkusZeller aparently yes it does

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide us [mcve].

Comment: If you just want to store the URL part in a variable, do the same as you've done but remove the HTML: `$imageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($row['image']);`. If that's not what you mean, then I'm clueless what you're asking about.

Comment: I suppose you have newlines in the base64 encoded string. Strip \r and \n.

Comment: @MarkusZeller - `base64_encode()` doesn't return a string with new lines.